# Why does some java code/quartz-code require a .class file?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, .class-file

Why does quartz or any java code require a .class file ? What is so special about the .class file that a regular api cannot provide ?

Code -

```
 JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
        .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();
```

source - http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-2-scheduler-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Java code is compiled into `.class` files, so that shouldn't be surprising.

But I think you're referring to the `Foo.class` *syntax*, which has nothing to do with `.class` files. It's simply a way to define a literal value of type `Class<T>`, much like you can use double quotes to define literal values of type `String`.

Comment: Daniel - Thanks. I saw the api for the class called "Class". Why do we need this class? Why does the above code need Hello.class ? Why can't it use an  Object of type HelloJob instead ?

Comment: There's a difference between a *class* and an *instance* of that class, or, more formally, between a *type* and a *value* of that type. When you're doing *metaprogramming* you often need to refer to types, not values (or higher-order concepts like *kinds* and *typeclasses* which Java doesn't have). See also the answers to [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-class-objectjava-lang-class-in-java).

Comment: Thanks again. Makes perfect sense now.