# Object class in android

Tags: java, android, oop

What is the use of Object class in android. The documentation of android doesn't clearly clears what it means.
eg ArrayList we use it store value of any type in particular key.
But I am unable to find out whay is the analogy behind it.
My last question is why to use that object class and in which circumstances we can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object class, as others pointed out is like a 'Mother Class', which all other classes directly or indirectly derive from. That said, it's oftenly used as a 'Generic' class which you can use to return or pass arguments of ANY type. e.g. : You are creating a generic callback that can receive some types, you could define it as: `myCallback(Object result){}`, so, when passing this callback, you can cast it to any type you'd like, eg. `Integer res = (Integer) result;` or `String res = (String) result;` and so on.
Object also has the toString method, that returns some information about your object eg:
You have a Person class with String name and String lastName, you could override toString to do so `toString(){ return this.name + " " + this.lastName; }`.
Another use of the Object class is when using the synchronized field (multithreading). eg:

```
Object lock = new Object(); 
public void anyConcurrentFunction(){
   synchronized(lock){
   do something here...
  }
}
```

And some other general stuff.

Hope I could help !

Answer (score 2):

By default, every custom type that you create extends `Object`.  From the Android API:

> The root class of the Java class hierarchy. All non-primitive types (including arrays) inherit either directly or indirectly from this class.

Due to the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), any class that is a subtype of another can be said to be replaced with its supertype.

For example, you could express this:

```
Object number = Integer.valueOf(17);
```

...even though it would be strange to do so.

Comment: can you please elaborate it

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Android question, it's a Java question.  In Java, all classes are derived from Object either directly or eventually.  Thus if a function takes an Object, it means it can take any value of any class.  If it returns Object it can return any class, and generally you should know the specific class it will return.

Comment: eg **ArrayList<Hashmap<String,Object>>** what does the object act in this case

Comment: THat's a generic specification.  You're saying that you have an arraylist of hashmaps, and that those hashmaps use Strings as keys and Objects as values.  So it can hold anything as a value.

Comment: ok i got some explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-class-objectjava-lang-class-in-java