# How to use multiple wildcards in an API call

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, anthill, unbounded-wildcard

I'm working with Anthill (an UrbanCode/IBM product) and one of the methods requires a parameter of type `java.lang.Class<? extends SourceConfig<?>> sourceConfigType`.

After reading the [tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) I found that a class `GitSourceConfig` is a subclass of `SourceConfig` but I don't understand how the generic of `SourceConfig<?>` works in this context. Any ideas?

The end goal is to get a `GitSourceConfig` object and call the `getRepositoryUrl`/`setRepositoryUrl` methods.  The Anthill Pro API is [here](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/documentation/product_doc/UrbanCode/AnthillPro/remoting/api/index.html) and I'm looking at the `SourceConfig` class.

Answer (score 0):

The generic [bounded wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) type in your example `java.lang.Class<? extends SourceConfig<?>> sourceConfigType` specifies that `sourceConfigType` is **any** class that can be bound by the *upper bound* type of `SourceConfig`.

From the tutorial,

> `List<? extends Shape>` is an example of a bounded wildcard. The ? stands for an unknown type, just like the wildcards we saw earlier. However, in this case, we know that this unknown type is in fact a subtype of `Shape`. (Note: It could be `Shape` itself, or some subclass; it need not literally extend `Shape`.)

**Note** `SourceConfig` itself is also generic, and here it is using a regular unbounded wildcard.

Comment: I think OP's confusion stems from the fact that `SourceConfig` itself is generic, and has a wildcard too.

Comment: @TomG Exactly. How do you work with that? I understand `GitSourceConfig extends SourceConfig` but I don't understand how the second generic works.

Comment: @Wheeler See (unbounded) wildcards in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Class` is generic -- if you invoke `getClass()` on a `String` object result will be of type `Class<String>`.

In this case `SourceConfig<R extends Repository>` itself a generic so you have nested generics.

if you check definition of `GitSourceConfig`

```
public class GitSourceConfig extends SourceConfig<GitRepository>
```

and

```
public class GitRepository extends Repository
```

so `Class<GitSourceConfig>` matches `Class<? extends SourceConfig<?>>`

Comment: After a little research, it looks like I'd use this as:  
`Class<GitSourceConfig> GitSourceConfigClass = (Class<GitSourceConfig>) p.getSourceConfigType();`  
`GitSourceConfig gsc = GitSourceConfigClass.newInstance();`  
This will give me the default constructor for a `GitSourceConfig` object.  My source is the second answer on **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-class-objectjava-lang-class-in-java)**.