# Why passing .class name in constructor function in Java

Tags: java

I have seen so many *Java* code examples passing *.class as a parameter to the *constructor* function. Why would I do that? When would I do that?

For ex.:

```
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
```

Comment: when constructor asks for a class object.

Comment: Then I can pass something like ABC a=new ABC(); and I can pass object a right ? Why would I do something like ABC.class ?

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is used to allow Reflection in Java to create concrete versions of the class passed in. For example, `Arrays.copyOfRange(...)` has an overload that takes a class parameter to return an actual Array typed with the Class[] that is passed into the method.

Without the parameter, it will return an `Object[]`. With the parameter, it will return an array like this, for example, `SomeClass[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`T.class` has the type `Class<T>`. It gives you access to the class itself as an object. The [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) have a number of different examples of how you can get a `Class<T>` object.

They're generally used with reflection to do some meta-manipulation on the class itself. There's an [SO thread with some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-class-objectjava-lang-class-in-java).

For example, I might define a `Logger` object that takes a `Class<T>` as a parameter. Then it could do things like:

```
class LoggerForClass<T> {
    String className;

    public LoggerForClass(Class<T> klass) {
        className = klass.getName();
    }

    public String log(String message) {
        return className + ": " + message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is obviously looking for a class object, but I think you might be asking a deeper question as to why an instance of one class would like to know about a different class. There are many reasons for this, but they mostly revolve around reflection. Reflection allows a program to inspect the structure of a class, it's constructors, methods, interfaces, etc by name, and then be able to call them.