# How can we create a class like Object class in java

Tags: java

In java, every class extends `Object` by default, like that, how we can make our class A can be extends by  any class in our application by default.

Comment: Did you mean *should - be* extended instead of *can-be*?. All *non-final* classes can be extended.

Comment: There is no way of implicitly having every class in your project extends a class. Object is the only class that classes extend by default. You could of course create a class and have every class explicitly extend it.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer - you can't.

The slightly longer answer - you can create you own custom empty class...

```
public class MyObject {
}
```

.. and make every class in your project extend it...

```
public class MyOtherClass extends MyObject {
    public int doStuff();
}
```

... but it's really unlikely there'll be any (good) use for this.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The class that other classes extend *by default* is `Object`.  You cannot change that.  It is a fundamental part of the Java language.

The [JLS 8.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) says:

> Given a (possibly generic) class declaration `C<F1,...,Fn> (n ≥ 0, C ≠ Object)`, the direct superclass of the class type `C<F1,...,Fn>` is the type given in the `extends` clause of the declaration of `C` if an `extends` clause is present, or `Object` otherwise.

There is no "wriggle room".

---

If you want all of the classes in your applications to be subclasses of something other than `Object`, then you *must* have an `extends` clause on each and every one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define an own class as a replacement for the Object class.

You can however create your own base class and let all your classes extend from that base class.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer: You Cannot !!

- `Object class` is the parent of all the `classes` in java
- What ever `classes` you use is a subclass of `object class` by
  default
- You can guarantee there will always be certain methods, like
  `toString()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()`, etc.
- It helps in `synchronization`, `garbage collection` etc

---

### Why it is like this:

> Java is designed this way so Object class helps by providing all the above mentioned and more 
>   features which are fundamental for object communication and object identifying so to have these 
>   functionality explicitly extending a class not required

---

### More information:

1. [Have a look at this Stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453378/1083093)
2. [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)
3. [Grep Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that.

You just have to explicitly make every class extend A. like so

```
public class B extends A {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't.

Object class is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly impossible to do it without explicitly using `extends`. `Object` is the parent class of every Java `Class`, so I think you'll need to stick to it. Apart from that, you can always extend a class with the one you like.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.