# Could you please explain this piece of code in terms of C# code?

Tags: java, c#, generics, kotlin, type-erasure

From the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#convenient-form-for-a-generic-function-that-requires-the-generic-type-information) page:

```
//  public final class Gson {
//     ...
//     public <T> T fromJson(JsonElement json, 
//                           Class<T> classOfT) 
//                           throws JsonSyntaxException {
//     ...
```

In the code snippet above, I understand everything except that `Class<T>` thing. I assume it is the C# equivalent of the following:

```
public sealed class Gson
{
  public T FromJson<T>(JsonElement json, 
                       System.Type Type)
  {
  }
}
```

And the client code would say something like:

```
var gson = new Gson();
var customer = gson.FromJson<Customer>(json, typeof(Customer));
```

But I can't be sure because that whole `System.Type` parameter seems redundant in the face of the generic type parameter `T` in the method definition.

Also, at the same location on that page, what's that `class.java` in the following snippet?

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> Gson.fromJson(json): 
                T = this.fromJson(json, T::class.java)
```

I assume that the class `Class` in Java is similar to `System.Type` so if you wanted to say, `typeof(Customer)`, you'd say `Customer.class`? Is that correct?

What's `class.java`?

Comment: Java generic types aren't available at runtime. You have to pass them as parameters if the method needs to know them. And the `class.java` is a well-documented Kotlin compatibility construct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the Class object (java.lang.Class)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-the-class-object-java-lang-class)

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet Not a relevant duplicate; the question is about generic erasure.

Comment: @chrylis Thank you. That answers my question about the need for the `Class<T>` parameter. What's `class.java`? I've updated the question to include another snippet, this time in Kotlin.

Comment: @chrylis So I should ignore his question? **What's class.java?**

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet The question you linked to simply confirms my suspicion that the `Class` class in Java is the equivalent of the `System.Type` in the CLR. It doesn't answer the whole question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java has *generic type erasure*: The actual type `T` is not available to code at runtime. Since Gson needs to know what the target deserialization type is, passing the `Class<T>` explicitly identifies it.

Kotlin, on the other hand, has a somewhat stronger type system than Java, and since the function there is inlined, the compiler knows what the generic type actually is (the `reified` keyword). The construct `T::class.java` tells the Kotlin compiler to determine what the appropriate type `T` is and then inline the class reference to `T`.

This inline redefinition is essentially syntactic sugar for Kotlin, allowing Kotlin users to delegate the hardcoded specification of the destination type to the compiler's inference.