# You cannot autowire so-called simple properties such as primitives, Strings, and Classes

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring and looking for detail learning. I was reading about autowiring and read `You cannot autowire so-called simple properties such as primitives, Strings, and Classes (and arrays of such simple properties)` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-exceptions).

**1)** I didn't understand what does it mean by `Classes` here?

**2)** They said you can't autowire primities, but I tried for `Integer` wrapper classes, they are still not working, why? See the code below.

**Beans:**

```
<bean id="teacher" class="com.climesoft.webapp.model.Teacher"
        autowire="byName">
</bean>
<bean id="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <constructor-arg value="20" />
</bean>
```

**Java Class Here:**

```
public class Teacher {

    private String name;
//  private int id;
    private Integer id; // for autowiring
    private String phone;
    private Course course;


    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public Teacher() {
        System.out.println("Calling Teacher No Param Constructor");
    }

    public Teacher(String name, Integer id, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.phone = phone;

        System.out.println("Calling Teacher Param Constructor");
    }

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("Calling Teacher getName");
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Calling Teacher setName");
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        System.out.println("Calling Teacher getId");
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        System.out.println("Calling Teacher setId");
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        System.out.println("Calling Teacher getPhone");
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        System.out.println("Calling Teacher setPhone");
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Teacher [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + ", phone=" + phone + ", course=" + course + "]";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some paratheses issue with the sentence that may be stopping you to understand it properly.

It can be a little more understandable as follows:

> You cannot autowire so-called simple properties such as primitives,
>   Strings, and Classes (and arrays) of such simple properties.

Anyways, what it actually means is that Any primitive, String and Classes of primitives (i.e. Wrapper classes like Integer), arrays of primitives/String/Wrappers cannot be autowired.

Autowiring from its very nature helps us wire the user-defined (and framework defined of course) classes whereas all the above-mentioned stuff can be quite complex to wire by default because of ambiguities involved.

Comment: IS this really true? i just created 2 beans one which returns a String and other an Integer and the autowired worked

Answer (score 0):

- You can't auto-wire primitive types like (int, boolean, long, short,
  byte) and all.
- Auto-wiring can only be done to a classes which are children of Object class (Directly or Indirectly).

So Basically, Autowiring is nothing but you are referencing the object(or Bean) of the class in your dependent class. As int, double, byte all these not objects but primitive types they cannot be autowired.

But you can use the object counter-parts of those primitive types like **String**, **Integer**, **Boolean** you can autowire these.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can create a bean with type of Class:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
   <constructor-arg value="com.MyClass"/>
</bean>
```

---

You can autowire int:

```
<bean id="autowiredInt" class="java.lang.Integer" factory-method="valueOf">
<constructor-arg value="100"/></bean>
```

And then:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("autowiredInt") 
private int autowiredInt;
```

Or you can use [@Value](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) annotation.

Comment: Hi string have more than 1 public constructors.  You can check the String source code.

Comment: Yes, but Class doesnt.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java

Comment: They wrote `Classes` not `Class`

Comment: `Strings` = any object with type of `String`, `Classes` = any object with type of  `Class`

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate this one?

Comment: A `Class` object is sort of a meta object describing the class of an object. It is used mostly with the reflection capabilities of Java. You can think of it like a "blueprint" of the actual class. 

You can read more at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-class-class-java-set-1/
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-the-class-object-java-lang-class

Comment: As each class have .class object? then why I was able to autowire my custom class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179275/discussion-between-freemahn-and-asif-mushtaq).