# Class type in java -spring mongodb source code

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I was going through the source code of Spring-MongoDB project. Here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/TypedAggregation.java

I found a Type called Class like below

```
private final Class<I> inputType;
```

I became curious as to what is this Class type , I looked up if there is any keyword of java which pertains to any Type Class, I haven't found any, Then I looked upon in the package if there is a Interface or Class of with name

> Class

But I haven't found any, Those are the only possibilities of my set of assumptions I can make. Can someone help with what is Class here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Class` refers to the representation of a Java class at runtime. It is a fundamental part of the Java reflection API, which **allows you to examine and interact with the structure and behavior of classes and objects** dynamically, at runtime.

The class `Class` is part of the java.lang package and is itself a class. It provides various methods that allow you to **access information about a class**, such as its name, modifiers, fields, methods, constructors, superclasses, interfaces, annotations, etc.

For example:

```java
Class<String> clazz = String.class;
System.out.println(clazz.getName());       // Output: java.lang.String
System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName()); // Output: String
```

Check this out:

- [What is the Class object (java.lang.Class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-the-class-object-java-lang-class)
- [Class (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)
- [Java.lang.Class class in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-class-class-java-set-1/)

Comment: One correction though @Diego Borba, This class Class is there in Java since 1.0 , not from Java 8. Please verify and correct, and also thanks for your answer.

Comment: @NaseerMohammad I know, but what I wanted to say is that my knowledge is from Java 8, the class can be modified in newer versions. But it is really open to bad interpretation, I have made some changes. Thanks for the recommendation!